# WordPress Theme Preview Image

Tags: theme-development, images, previews

I'm developing a custom WordPress theme. When I go to select themes in the Appearance menu, my theme does not have a preview image. Is there something I need to do to get a preview image to show up? I can't find any resources on the web that talk about this. Maybe I'm just searching the wrong thing though...?

Comment: Found it-- I was searching the wrong thing, but this also isn't very well documented. In order to get a screenshot to show up for your theme, you need to include a file called screenshot.png in the root folder of your theme. This is preferably 300x225 but that isn't required.

Comment: You should post this as Answer, so you can mark it as solution. Else the Q will stay open forever.

Comment: I know, I couldn't because I don't have a rep of 100 or above before.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no automatic preview.  You need to create the screenshot yourself and place it in the theme/child theme folder named screenshot.png

The recommended image size (currently) is 1200px wide by 900px tall, however the screenshot will only be shown as 387x290. It is over-sized to allow for high-resolution viewing on HiDPI displays. Note that as of version 4.7.4, the bottom ~18% of this image will be cutoff so keep logos or other graphics centered.

For the latest info see:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Screenshot

Answer (score 6):

For wordpress.org themes, the screenshot should be reasonable facsimile of the theme, and should be 880px wide and 660px in height (any 4:3 height:width) screenshot will be fine.

To add a screenshot, create screenshot.png file and add it to the root director of the theme. e.g wp-content/themes/theme-name/

**How to create a screenshot of the theme.**

You can use screengrab, awesome screenshot or any other firefox addon or chrome extension to take screenshot and set height and width in photoshop. You can also use built-in feature of firefox for this reason.

- [aswsome screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/)
- [screengrab for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab-fix-version/)

Click on alt button on your keyboard and you will see a menu at the top of the browser, Click on *tools > web developer > responsive design view*, now set custom height width and take screenshot

Comment: Greenshot is another great tool for taking screenshots:

http://getgreenshot.org/